# Angular 4: use of ngModel two-way binding instead of [checked] gets rid of the 'name' attribute

Tags: html, angular

I have searched through existing questions related to this and have found people mostly denying it happening, I checked my configuration to no avail, tried several things including [suggestions on this page](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel).

Here is my checkbox

```
<div *ngFor="let customer of customers; let customerIndex=index">
 <input type="checkbox" value="on" name="Customer_{{customerIndex}}" [checked]="customer.isSelected" />
</div>
```

The above code works fine and I see the following in Chrome inspector.

[image: Chrome Inspector showing name of the element]

Now when I change my checkbox to use two-way binding like so

```
<div *ngFor="let customer of customers; let customerIndex=index">
 <input type="checkbox" value="on" name="Customer_{{customerIndex}}" [(ngModel)]="customer.isSelected" />
</div>
```

The Chrome inspector shows that the `name` attribute is gone.

[image: Chrome Inspector showing no name of the element]

How do I use two-way binding to my checkbox and preserve the `name` attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `[attr.name]="'Customer_' + customerIndex"` instead of `name="...`

Comment: You're welcome. I don't think they do, you can try, though.

Comment: No they don't Tried.